# Clojure Cake build tool isn't working properly

Tags: clojure

I installed this Clojure Textmate bundle:
https://github.com/swannodette/textmate-clojure
and Cake build tool:
https://github.com/ninjudd/cake

Running cake start in the terminal, I got these warnings (actually, all Cake commands are generating these warning):

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cake-0.5.8/bin/cake:43: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cake-0.5.8/bin/cake:43: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777

Why I'm getting these warnings?

And many cake command are generating the error message:

> unknown task

Any idea what is wrong with Cake?

Answer (score 1):

Cake is (11/2010) evolving very quickly these days so I found using the git stream to work more often for me. When I encounter bugs like this one i first update cake and then re run `cake deps`. some days are better than others.